# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a question, why I get this error when i install for `ionic`, error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in github.com

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443
>
> Creating Ionic app in folder ~..\conference base d on sidemenu project Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip Error Initializing app: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443

Anyone gotten this to work correctly that could share what they did?
Here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKoiU.jpg)

Comment: Which command did you run exactly?

Comment: Which version of npm are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Please try following steps one by one, it will help:

1. try clearing cache: `npm cache clean`
2. set correct proxy: 
   `npm set proxy http://yourproxy:port`
3. if error persists, contact your admin/proxy provider

Answer (score 2):

Install it via npm.

Download node.js.

Run command: `npm install -g ionic`

-g will surmount the need of specifying the ionic so that you can access ionic as soon as you install it.

Comment: I've have to re install ionic ??

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a connectivity issue, Ionic needs a network connection to get the templates for projects when you start them as well as gradle files etc when you try to run them in a device. As Pawan suggested it is most likely a proxy issue, here is an article describing the usage if that is the case:

Instead of setting the NPM proxy settings, try this:

set proxy=http://yourproxy:port

*notice the lack of npm at the beginning of the statement.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a connectivity issue.
Check your internet connection, the error message said that it can't found DNS(domain name system) server and can't translate the domain github to respected address(IP).

Answer (score 0):

thi error is generally because npm can not able to download necessary files for your project .so it is due to your net whether you dont have internet connection or you dont have set the proxy

try this
set http_proxy=http://192.168.0.14:3128  http will be different for your pc .

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things did not worked for me ... Request you to please do this ..will work ...

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2017/04/using-npm-behind-a-proxy-that-uses-ntlm-authentication/ http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2017/04/using-npm-behind-a-proxy-that-uses-ntlm-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

default proxy part :8080
can close Xampp And Skype or other program use it port